# Angular project architecture. Controllers. Directives. Style guides

Tags: javascript, angularjs

We currently have a project that we are going to scale up soon. I am in the process of refactoring the project to make sure it's a bit more maintainable in the long term, and isn't a complete headache for anyone new to the project.

Please ignore any syntactical errors below, I had to change a bit of the code to try and best illustrate the architectural issue.

We have tried to follow the john papa style guide as closely as possible.

currently our setup is as follows:

PageController

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('front')
        .controller('PageController', PageController)

    /** @ngInject */
    function PageController($rootScope, $scope, $timeout, toastr, dataService, allowed, Pusher) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.allowed = allowed;

        vm.widget = {

        };


        activate();

        function activate(){
            getOurWidgetData();


        } // end activate()



        /* get widget data */
        function getOurWidgetData() {
            dataService.getData(
                $rootScope.wf.api + '/endpoint',
                function(response) {
                    vm.widget.data = response.data.data;
                    vm.widgetlastModified = new Date(response.data.timestamp * 1000);
                },
                function(error) {
                    vm.widget.error = error;
                }
            );
        }

        vm.getOurWidgetData = getOurWidgetData;
    }
})();
```

In our PageController view:

```
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
        <div class="panel">
          <div class="panel__header">
            <h2><span>Widget</span>
              <last-updated last-updated="main.widget.lastModified" lu-error="main.widget.error" label="As at"></last-updated>
            </h2>
          </div>
          <div class="panel__body">
            <div our-widget="" our-data="main.widget.data"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

and then in OurWidget:

```
    (function() {
      'use strict';

      angular

    .module('front')
    .directive('ourWidget', ourWidget);

  /** @ngInject */
  function ourWidget() {
    var directive = {
      restrict: 'A',
      templateUrl: 'app/components/ourWidget/ourWidget.html',
      scope: {
        aumData: '='
      },
      controller: ourWidgetController,
      controllerAs: 'ow',
      bindToController: true
    };

    return directive;

    /** @ngInject */
    function ourWidgetController() {

      var vm = this;

      activate();

      function activate() {

      }



    }

  }

})();
```

Now, this directive / component is quite empty. My proposal at this point is to move the dataService call from the PageController and into the component.

So, the ourWidget directive looks like this:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('front')
        .directive('ourWidget', ourWidget);

    function ourWidget() {
        var directive = {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'app/components/ourWidget/ourwidget.html',
            scope: {
                ourModel: '='
            },
            controller: ourWidgetController,
            controllerAs: 'ow',
            bindToController: true
        };

        return directive;

        /** @ngInject */
        function ourWidgetController($rootScope, dataService, constants, endpoints, $log) {

            var vm = this;
            vm.OurWidget = {};

            activate();

            function activate() {

                getOurWidgetData();

            } // end activate()

            function getOurWidgetData() {
                dataService.getData(
                    constants.apiv2 + endpoints.OurWidget,
                    function(response) {
                        $log.log(response);
                        vm.OurWidget.data = response.data.data;
                        vm.OurWidget.lastModified = new Date(response.data.timestamp * 1000);
                    },
                    function(error) {
                        vm.OurWidget.error = error;
                    }
                );
            }

            vm.getOurWidgetData = getOurWidgetData;
        }

    }

})();
```

I have prototyped this and it works flawlessly, meaning I have a html tag like:

```
<our-widget></our-widget>
```

That I can put anywhere in the application I need it. This directive is now responsible for its data, and means we aren't copy pasting dataService calls across any page controller that this component would be needed.

My question is, is this a better way of doing it, having the dataService call inside the component / directive instead of the PageController? I'd say it *is*, as our previous method goes directly against the DRY principle. I'm getting a bit of resistance though as some suggest it is going against the Angular style guide, though I haven't seen any examples or suggestion not to do it in this way, or in fact anything alluding to this kind of project architecture besides having a dataService handle all our http request, which we already have.

And yes, I've noticed we're using $rootScope incorrectly, I am attempting to fix these things as I'm going along :)